# Masstransit IRequestClient.Request call from the Quartz job deadlock

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz.net, masstransit

I have a report which calls business service through the Masstransit IRequestClient.Request method call.

If this report is build from the UI (ASP.NET MVC controller) everything works, but if the same report is building from the Quartz .net job method call never returns.

Here is code sample:

```
//client is an instance of MessageRequestClient class
var response = await client.Request(new GetEntityCommand
        {
            Ids = ids,
            ExcludeDeleted = excludeDeleted
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Consumer code:

```
public class GetEntityCommandConsumer : IConsumer<IGetEntityCommand>
{
    private readonly IEntityService _entityService;

    public GetEntityCommandConsumer(IEntityService entityService)
    {
        _entityService= entityService;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IGetEntityCommand> context)
    {
        var ids = context.Message.Ids;
        var entities = _entityService.GetAll(ids, context.Message.ExcludeDeleted); //database NHibernate call
        var result =
            context.RespondAsync(new GetEntityCommandResponse
            {
                Success = true,
                Entities = entities.Select(x => x.ToDTO).ToList()
            });

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to see the consumer code as well.

Comment: Added consumer code to the root message. Consumer code resides inside console application. Debugger shows that consumer has been called. Seems that MT need some thread to return task results, but it is blocked by other code.

Comment: Have you tried making the consume method async and instead of returning the task, call `await context.RespondAsync(...)`?

Comment: I am not sure where the Quartz there in the consumer.

Comment: No, I haven't tried call `await context.RespondAsync()`. Quartz is not on the consumer side, it is on ASP.NET MVC application side, which calls `await client.Request(...)`

Comment: May be you want to try it. We use Request/Response and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual problem was in my own code :) There were two instances of IBusControl but expected only one. IBusControl which was used from the job was not started. Fixed by using "true" singletoned IBusControl.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the consumer call is not being awaited and the scope gets disposed before it completes so you get a deadlock.

Try this:

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IGetEntityCommand> context)
{
    var ids = context.Message.Ids;
    var entities = _entityService.GetAll(ids, context.Message.ExcludeDeleted); //database NHibernate call
    await
        context.RespondAsync(new GetEntityCommandResponse
        {
            Success = true,
            Entities = entities.Select(x => x.ToDTO).ToList()
        });
}
```

Comment: Still getting deadlock. Please, note, that message consumer is inside separate process. I think that consumer is OK, something wrong with threads inside IRequestClient which used from job.

Comment: I don't think so. We never had issues with `IRequestClient`. It can be the code that calls the request client. I would try making the method synchronous and call `TaskUtil.Await(() => client.Request(...));`